# returning require_once and some text results in require_once failing

Tags: php

```
// File that is run
echo require_once('required.php').'<br />';

// required.php
return 'Some text';
```

According to [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-144), the above should output `Some text<br />`. However, the following error is generated instead:

```
Warning: require_once(required.php<br />): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

I've discovered that I can resolve the issue by doing `echo (require_once('required.php')).'<br />';`, but I'm still not sure why this happens.

Can anybody explain why this error occurs? Am I overlooking something obvious? I'm using PHP 5.5.8

Comment: remove `<br />` tag from `require_once` and don't echo `require_once`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Require_once`, as `include`, is not a method but a statement (as mentioned in your PHP doc link), but the alternate method syntax is allowed (no reference here).

It means that, for PHP :

```
include('file.php') === include 'file.php'
```

So if you append some string to your include, it will append it at runtime to the include path, as :

```
include('file.php').'string' === include 'file.php'.'string'
=== include 'file.phpstring'
```

Comment: I knew of the alternate syntax, but didn't think of it when I ran into this problem. That explains everything. Thanks.